# Out of memory in onActivityResult

Tags: android, exception, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have gallery intent that copy imege to folder, and the all that images shown in the ListView. I have an OutOfMemory Exception with bitmap decoding in my compress method - what is the simpliest way to fix it? I have recycle() option, but it's not helped.

here is my onActivityResult and compress:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                //Toast.makeText(this, selectedImagePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                String path = "MANUAL/workflow/img" + actions.id() + ".png";
                String pathCom = "/MANUAL/workflow/img" + actions.id() + ".png";
                File from = new File(selectedImagePath);
                File to = new File(sdcard, path);
                try {
                    copy(from, to);
                    compress(pathCom);
                } catch (IOException io){}

                //from.renameTo(to); 
            }
        }
    }


    public void compress(String comp) {
        try {

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + comp;

            BitmapFactory.Options buffer = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            buffer.inSampleSize = 1;
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, buffer);

            if (bmp.getWidth() > width || bmp.getHeight() > height){
                Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,(int)(bmp.getWidth()*0.2), (int)(bmp.getHeight()*0.2), true);
                bmp.recycle();
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
                resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70, out);
                resized.recycle();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("saveBitmap", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

herу is my intent:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.gallery:
                // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
                // select a file
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `inSampleSize` is set to 1 which means its basically not being used.. 1= no downsampling  2 would be 1/2,  4 a 1/4.

also look into this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

hope that helps.

also if the purpose of this is to just simply create a scaled image file, perhaps that task should be handled on it's own thread using an AsyncTask for that image resizing

Comment: what if I don't whant it to be resized?

Comment: every device is going to have different memory restrictions and ultimately i assure you, you will rarely be viewing the image at it's full size.  If you don't downsample it, you will almost always run into memory exceptions on somedevices